# How to get a high quality recorded audio from RecognitionListener in android SpeechRecognizer?

Tags: android, kotlin, uri, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I try to get a proper audio uri from android `SpeechRecognizer` at the end of recording without starting the intent because I don't need it's UI showing up on my own recording microphone UI.

Setting the `ACTION_VOICE_SEARCH_HANDS_FREE` flag when initializing the `RecognizerIntent` doesn't help also.

As you may know `RecognitionListener` is sending the intent extras values as a bundle on it's `onResult` method and is not sending the intent data which is that needed uri and it forces me to start the recognition intent so what should I do? what trick is there to implement?

Answer (score -1):

This is how I listen to speech without opening the dialog

```
private void listenForControl() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, preferredLanguage);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, preferredLanguage);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "prompt");
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PREFER_OFFLINE, false);
    mSpeechRecognizerForController = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(this);
    mSpeechRecognizerForController.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onRmsChanged(float v) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferReceived(byte[] bytes) {
            //you can get audio bytes from here
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndOfSpeech() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(int i) {
            mSpeechRecognizerForController.stopListening();
            mSpeechRecognizerForController.destroy();
            //listenHandler.postDelayed(listenRunnable, 2000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onResults(Bundle bundle) {
            ArrayList result = bundle
                    .getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
            String msg = result.get(0).toString();
            sendMessage(msg);
            mSpeechRecognizerForController.stopListening();
            mSpeechRecognizerForController.destroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPartialResults(Bundle bundle) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onEvent(int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });
    mSpeechRecognizerForController.startListening(intent);
}
```

Comment: thanks but where is the audio uri that I need?

Comment: Store that byte array into an audio file in files directory and get the URI of that file.

Comment: thank you I'll try it and keep you inform